# Cart updating only after refreshing the page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

Webshop on Magento 1.9.1.1

In the product page, when I add an item to the cart, it is not immediately updated. I can see the product added to the cart only after a refresh of the page.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: are you using a custom theme?

Comment: It's the Ultimo Theme with some custom modifications like two custom landing pages and an ajax cart extension @Haim

Comment: What Ajax cart extension?

Comment: https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/ajax-cart-pro.html @Haim

Comment: when the Ajax returns the data it needs to know the block name of the cart to update, you will either need to get a dev to fix this for you or you can ask AW or Ultimo to sort this out for you - they're a popular theme and extension, so I'm sure you're not the first one to come across this

Comment: @Haim Many thanks for suggesting, I will contact Ultimo Theme!